# Install4j Uninstall Previous Installation does not show all screens from Uninstaller

Tags: install4j

We have created a custom Welcome screen (Configurable banner form) to upgrade and remove application with the help of install4j.

[image: Custom Welcome Screen]

We are providing radio button to remove an application using action **Uninstall Previous Installation** and we perform successful uninstall from this action, but my uninstall wizard consists few Screens, Actions and Display progress screens which are not displayed during uninstall process.\

[image]

How can we show the all these screens, actions to user which we have added in the uninstaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Ingo,  Install4j execute the uninstaller of previous installer and it is not showing any screen to user.

We need to design custom screens for **uninstall  previous installation** hence added required screens with condition expression.

[image]

And this works for me. Thanks Ingo.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The "Uninstall previous installation" executes the uninstaller of the previous installation. If you have additional actions that are not contained in the previous uninstaller you have to add them to the "Welcome" screen and give them a condition expression of

```
context.isUpdateInstallation()
```

Similary, you can add screens that are only shown for an update installation.